# Sound indications for correct/wrong input in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have an Xamarin Android app with an attached barcode scanner. If the user scans the right barcode I want a audio clue (something like a bing) and if the wrong barcode is scanned I want a negative short sound to play.

Edit:
the clearify thing. I just need the smartphone to play a confirmation/fail sound. The input into the smartphone is unimportant.

Comment: Which library you have used for barcode scanning ?

Comment: It's important to know how you are reading the data in as there probably are events (e.g. OnScan, OnScanError) that you can use.  Otherwise you could use a function to save the value which then plays the sound (e.g. `void saveScan(string value){_val = value; playOkSound();}`)

Comment: I would like to know how to implement the playOkSound() function not where to put it.

Comment: How did you scan barcode? show your code please, usually there will be result when you scan successfully, you can play sounds depending on that result.

Comment: I know when and where I scan the right barcode I don't know how to play sounds